# Best practice for port binding two gitlab containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-container

We want to have two instances of gitlab running on our server. One will be maintained for legacy reasons and a new one going forward for new projects.

Using docker, we were able to bring up the first legacy instance of gitlab. Here is our docker-compose.yml minus our env variables and hostname.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    gitlab:
        container_name: 'gitlab_legacy'
        image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
        restart: 'always'
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '443:443'
            - '22:22'
        volumes:
            - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
            - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
            - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: nginx-proxy
```

My networking knowledge is limited but I know that obviously this won't work for the second instance as the ports will already be in use. The following errors will occur.

`Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated`
`Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated`
`Bind for 0.0.0.0:22 failed: port is already allocated`

So my question is what is the best solution to brining up a second gitlab dockerised container, or any future containers, which requires binding to the same ports?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an nginx rever proxy as explained in [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-bind-multiple-domains-ports-80-and-443-to-docker-contained-applications)

Then in your docker-compose file the ports part will be changed as described.
For example :

```
ports:
    - '7080:80'
    - '7443:443'
    - '7022:22'
```

and for the second instance :

```
ports:
    - '8080:80'
    - '8443:443'
    - '8022:22'
```

Comment: I am using jwilder/nginx-proxy